# Creating a symmetric array with power of an element

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, symmetric

I am trying to create an array which is symmetric with elements placed as below

[image: correct_pic]

I have written the following code to get this form with parameter being 0.5 and dimension being `4-by-4`.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.eye(4)
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        a[i, j] = (0.5) ** (np.abs(i-j))
```

This does what I need but for large dimension (1000s) this causes a lot of overhead. Is there any other low complexity method to get this matrix? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after creating a ranged array to represent the iterator variable and then performing an outer-subtraction to simulate `i-j` part -

```
n = 4
p = 0.5
I = np.arange(n)
out = p ** (np.abs(I[:,None]-I))
```

**Optimization #1**

We can do a hashing based one with `indexing`, so that we optimize on expensive power computations, like so -

```
out = (p**np.arange(n))[(np.abs(I[:,None]-I))]
```

**Optimization #2**

We can optimize further to use multi-cores with [`numexpr`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) -

```
import numexpr as ne

out = ne.evaluate('p**abs(I2D-I)',{'I2D':I[:,None],'I':I})
```

Comment: Thanks, broadcasting was what I was looking for.